# Django: URL reverse error

Tags: django, url

I have this url ref

```
{% url 'mahasiswa:mhs_delete' mhs.id %}

{% url 'mahasiswa:mhs_edit' mhs.id %}
```

with this pattern in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from mahasiswa import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', views.mhs_list, name='mhs_list'),
  url(r'^new$', views.mhs_create, name='mhs_new'),
  url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.mhs_update, name='mhs_edit'),
  url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.mhs_delete, name='mhs_delete'),
)
```

and i got the error:

> Reverse for 'mhs_edit' with arguments '(None,)' and keyword arguments
>   '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'mahasiswa/edit/(?P\d+)$']

help me to resolve it ...

Comment: Perhaps you don't have template variable called mhs or mhs is not saved. That why `mhs.id` is None. Install django debug toolbar and use tab "Templates" to see which variables are available in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one URL pattern for `mhs_edit` in your urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.mhs_update, name='mhs_edit')
```

But that view takes 1 argument: `pk` of type `\d+` (matching accepting any string of at least one digit). Arguments typle `(None,)` does not fit the prototype. You could try:

```
reverse('mhs_edit', args=(123,))
```

or

```
reverse('mhs_edit', args=("123",))
```